# How do you change the MIME on Amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, mp4

I am trying to change a mp4 video file's MIME that is stored on Amazon S3.

I tried searching under the properties listing when you right click and then the meta-data drop down. But there is no option for that there.

How do you I do that?

Comment: I am using presigned post to upload the docs . how can i set the metadata from there

Answer (score 19):

The issue does seem be to change the MIME in S3.

To be more specific, you need to log into Amazon S3 Console

[image]

- Right on the file you need to change (or select them)
- click on **properties**
- click on **metadata**
- HIGHLIGHT the text in "value" category (because "video/mp4" will not be in the drop down)
- manually type in "video/mp4"
- hit save

Comment: this will change all existing files, but is there a way to set the default type for all mp4 uploads to automatically use video/mp4 ?

Answer (score 1):

To change the content type, find the object in the AWS Console, go to the `Properties` tab and under `Metadata` add a `Content-Type` key with the required MIME type as the value for that key (e.g. `video/mp4`).