# How would I set the Content-type of an html document to "text/html"?

Tags: html

In one of your previous answers, you said that to get a "clean" link, you could set your content-type to "text/html" and remove the file extension.

[image]

If you could tell me how to do this, that would be great.

Comment: Please link to the answer you are talking about and quote the relevant content instead of linking to a screenshot of an out-of-context section of the answer.

Comment: The answer OP is referring to is from [S3 static pages without .html extension](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23466534/4642212).

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100858/how-do-you-change-the-mime-on-amazon-s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do the task :-

```
<meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

After doing this go to save as option in file and remove the .html extension. Hope this'll help.

Comment: Thanks, I give that a try :D

Comment: Thanks for your support. Always Welcome :)