# How do I set up a ServiceWorker on amazon S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, service-worker

I am trying to set up the service worker for a SPA I am making.  Its hosted on AWS with S3.

Despite the file being in the correct place I still get the following errors

/service-worker.js:1 The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/js').
https://djwdy6bk7t99o.cloudfront.net/service-worker.js

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Answer (score 2):

The [service worker specification](https://w3c.github.io/ServiceWorker/#update) requires that the response for the service worker JavaScript file used in the registration be served with a "[JavaScript MIME type](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#javascript-mime-type)" (e.g., `Content-Type: application/javascript`) header.

That's what I'd expect the default to be for files served by S3 with a `.js` extension, but perhaps you've previously overridden the default settings? [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100858/how-do-you-change-the-mime-on-amazon-s3) has some details about changing that setting back.

Comment: I guess the service worker comes from the same origin. If it is not served from the same origin browser will not let it register for that domain. It is also important for security purposes.