# Sending Twilio Fax from AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, twilio

I'm trying to send a fax from the Twilio service.

S3 bucket is used to store a file and giving that URL as media_url.

```
from twilio.rest import Client

account_sid = 'ABCD'
auth_token = 'XYZ'
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

fax = client.fax.faxes \
    .create(
         from_='+15017122661',
         to='+15558675310',
         media_url='http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-A/Test/test.docx'
     )
```

response :

```
{"media_sid": null, "status": "failed", "direction": "outbound"}
```

- Given S3 Public Access.

What to do with the S3 bucket to fetch a file from S3?

Thank you.

Tried with `media_url='http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket-A/Test/test.pdf'` same response

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

From your example, it appears you are trying to send an `.docx` file. Currently the [Twilio Fax API only supports sending PDF files](https://www.twilio.com/docs/fax/send). Can you try again with a PDF?

Comment: Thank you @philnash, Tried .pdf file but same response

Comment: Where are you seeing that error message? Is that the response from calling `faxes.create`? Is there any more detail in the error message or in the [Twilio debugger](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/debugger)?

Comment: GET : https://fax.twilio.com/v1/Faxes//{SID} from this i'm getting status

Comment: OK, is there anything in the debugger then? That might have more detail on why the media couldn't be sent.

Comment: Curious, did you set the proper file MIME type as well on S3? That has tripped me up with other use cases, here are the steps - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100858/how-do-you-change-the-mime-on-amazon-s3. It appears to me of type: application/pdf.